# Euler Maclaurin summation examples?

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

How does one use Euler Maclaurin to compute asymptotics for sums like
$$ \sum_{\substack{n\le x \\ (n,q)=1}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \quad \text{or} \quad \sum_{\substack{n\le x \\ (n,q)=1}} \frac{\log n}{\sqrt{n}}?$$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get asymptotics using Abel summation (see Tenenbaum's Introduction to Analytic and Probabilistic Number Theory, section 1.0).

We can let $b(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ and define $a_n$ to be $1$ if $(n,q)=1$ and 0 otherwise. Then
$$ \sum_{\substack{n\le x \\ (n,q)=1}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}
=\sum_{n \le x} a_n b(n)
=A(x)b(x) - \int_1^x A(t) b'(t) \, dt
= \frac{A(x)}{\sqrt{x}} + \frac{1}{2} \int_1^x A(t) t^{-3/2} \, dt
$$
where 
$$
A(x) = \sum_{n \le x} a_n = \frac{x}{q} \phi(q) + O(\phi(q)).$$
From this, we can determine that
$$\sum_{\substack{n\le x \\ (n,q)=1}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}
= 2 \sqrt{x} \frac{\phi(q)}{q} + O( \phi(q) ). $$
I am sure better bounds on the error terms are possible, but this might be good enough for what you want to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

We can actually get an additional term using the Wiener-Ikehara theorem.

Introduce the Dirichlet Series $A(s)$ whose terms are given by the indicator $(n, q) =1$ times $1/\sqrt{n}$. We have
$$ A(s) = \sum_{(n,q)=1} \frac{1/\sqrt{n}}{n^s} =
\sum_{(n,q)=1} \frac{1}{n^{s+\frac{1}{2}}} =
\prod_{p\nmid q} \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{p^{s+\frac{1}{2}}}} = 
\zeta\left(s+\frac{1}{2}\right) \prod_{p\mid q} 
\left(1-\frac{1}{p^{s+\frac{1}{2}}} \right),$$
where $p$ ranges over the primes.
Furthermore, introduce
$$ B(s) = A(s) - 
\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \prod_{p\mid q} \left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{p}}\right)$$
This Dirichlet series differs from $A(s)$ in its constant term and converges in $\mathfrak{R}(s) \ge \frac{1}{2}.$ It has a simple pole at $\frac{1}{2}$ and is zero at $s=0.$ Wiener-Ikehara applies to $B(s)$, giving

$$\sum_{k\le n,(k,n)=1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} 
- \zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \prod_{p\mid q} \left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{p}}\right)
\sim \prod_{p\mid q} \left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right) \frac{\sqrt{n}}{1/2} =
2 \frac{\phi(q)}{q} \sqrt{n}.$$
We construct the zero at $s=0$ because we are actually working with the Mellin-Perron type integral
$$\int_{1-i\infty}^{1+i\infty} B(s) n^s \frac{ds}{s}$$
and need to cancel the pole at $s=0$.

The conclusion is that
$$ \sum_{k\le n,(k,n)=1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} \sim
2 \frac{\phi(q)}{q} \sqrt{n} +
\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \prod_{p\mid q} \left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{p}}\right)$$
The numerics of this approximation are excellent even for small values of $n$.

Comment: OP asked "How does one use Euler Maclaurin", can you elaborate on that?